# Why does T-SQL allow both NULL and 'NULL'

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

When I run the following query:

```
select top 5 * from  BI_Completes (nolock)where IPAddress <> NULL
```

I get 0 results.

But if I run it as

```
select top 5 * from  BI_Completes (nolock)where IPAddress <> 'NULL'
```

then it works as expected..

What is the difference between these?

Comment: `'NULL'` is a string. `NULL` is the unknown value. The two are _very_ different.

Comment: I think his question is more about why `<> NULL` isn't returning what he expects.

Answer (score 8):

You can't use the comparison operators with NULLs because NULL can't be compared, neither with itself.
You must use instead, the IS operator:

```
select top 5 * 
from  BI_Completes (nolock)
where IPAddress IS NOT NULL
```

The second statement, checks where IPAddress is not equals to the character sequence 'NULL'.

Comment: Ah! I need to drill that in my head! Thank You !

Comment: +1 on proper way to compare to null

Answer (score 2):

The first snippet is just not correct. NULL <> NULL is always false, because NULL is never equal to itself by definition: you can't know if it equals itself or not, and so comparisons are *effectively* false.  The second snippet is using a string literal which just happens to not match any of your data.

The correct code you should use looks like this:

```
select top 5 * from  BI_Completes (nolock)where IPAddress IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: @DavidHoerster It isn't false. It is unknown as your answer says.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms191270%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) MSDN article talking about comparisons with `NULL`.

In your situation, looks like you're getting a result of `UNKNOWN`, which is why nothing is being returned.  Probably you have `ANSI_NULLS` set to `ON`, which is what would cause the value of `UNKNOWN` being returned..  Also, the 'NULL' that you're comparing against in the second example is a string comparison.

Andrea or Joel's answers about the proper way to handle NULL is correct (using `IS NOT NULL` instead of checking for equality).